# Is there something like hardlinks that split into separate files on modifications?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, symbolic-link, deduplication

Let's say files `orig` and `copy` are huge but identical files. In order to save storage space one could therefore either make `copy` a soft-link to `orig` or hard-link both files to the same data. `orig` must never be modified, while in the future `copy` may do so.

Can it be achieved that `copy` becomes a files of its own again the instance modifications are made to it, thus keeping `orig` unmodified at the expense of loosing the previously saved space again?

Comment: The general scheme is called *"copy on write"*. I am not aware of any file systems that do that, but it might help with searching.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-instance_storage and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication

Comment: On Windows, "Single instance storage" is quite similar. (For Linux, btrfs comes to mind: `cp --reflink`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with Windows as it normally works. You'd need something else to pull that particular stunt off.

If these files are being stored on a server, Windows Storage Server has a [Single Instance Store](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-instance_storage) feature that can give you something close to what you want.

[OpenDedup](http://opendedup.org/) is a cross platform file system implementation that does dedupe as well. You could run it on your desktop, if necessary.

There's also non-Windows server options as well. ZFS on Solaris and FreeBSD are particularly popular.

Finally, you can sometimes get lucky with just saving a file, but that depends on a particular application's save implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Some applications allow you to make a file a 'template'.

When you open that file it will create a new instance,
with the content and formatting of the template.